# Should HTML tags appear on their own separate line?

Tags: html

Which is better, putting an HTML element's tags on the same line as its content or on separate lines? For example:

```
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

versus

```
<p>
  Hello World!
</p>
```

Is there a styling convention that covers this? Or is this simply a matter of preference/consistency like the debate on whether curly braces should appear on their own line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me. Both of the above methods work. But:

The first way is using short content:

```
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

Second, I always use it when I have large content, or using framework CSS like bootstrap, tailwind CSS.... or If you use VsCode when you format document it will be like this for larger content.

```
  <p class="mt-2 text-base leading-6">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
      Voluptatibus quia, nulla! Maiores et perferendis eaque, 
      exercitationem praesentium nihil.
  </p>
```

I recommend the second way. Easy to read code